# Показ страницы после загрузки background-image

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем Здравствуйте, Как сделать так, чтобы background-image загружался до того как страница будет показана?

HTL

```
<div class="background"></div>
```

CSS

```
.background {
   background-image: url(img/background.png);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самому сделать такое сложновато (как я понял, когда сам искал решения).
Нашел такой [скриптик](http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/). Он позволяет выполнить скрипт после загрузки изображения с бекграунда, например, используя такой кодик (jQuery):

```
$('#container').imagesLoaded( 
  { background: true }, 
  function() {
    console.log('Бек-изображения загружены!');
});
```

Но я, пока использовал его, столкнулся с тем, что бекграунды у псевдоэлементов он не инициализирует и не отслеживает их загрузку (даже с использованием функции готовности DOM). Это нужно знать, думаю.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, сейчас буду пробовать!

Comment: @harbor, держи ссылку-якорь на гитхаб: https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded#background

Comment: что-то разобраться не могу, подключил `<script src="https://unpkg.com/imagesloaded@4.1/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<!-- or -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/imagesloaded@4.1/imagesloaded.pkgd.js"></script>`  добавил `$('#background').imagesLoaded( 
  { background: true }, 
  function() {
    console.log('Бек-изображения загружены!');
});` все верно? если да, то все равно видно как изображение загружается, надеюсь я где-то ошибся..

Comment: @harbor, а ты понимаешь, что делает этот код? Он выводит в консоль браузера (В хроме это Ctrl+Shift+J) сообщение `Бек-изображения загружены!`, когда картинка полностью загрузилась.
Правильно? Или он не выводит его тогда, когда они УЖЕ загрузились? Потому что тогда что-то не так, и это странно.

Comment: @harbor, чтобы не было видно загружающегося бекграунда у элемента, пока он, собственно, грузится, можно скрыть этот блок.  А показать, когда картинка уже загрузится, то есть добавить `$('#background').css('display', 'block')` вместо консольного вывода из моего примера, например.